# Find coordinates of point in a different coordinate frame

Tags: transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I would like to know the easiest ROS way (tf, geometry_msgs or something of the sort) to get the coordinates of a point in another coordinate frame defined by a pose.

Let's say, I have a point w coordinates x, y, z in a global frame and I have a pose of a local coordinate frame wrt the same global frame in the form of a geometry_msgs/Pose. Now how do I find x1, y1, z1 which are the coordinates of that point in the local coordinate frame (given by that pose)

Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/240365/find-coordinates-of-point-in-a-different-coordinate-frame/) by [2ROS0](https://answers.ros.org/users/18936/2ros0/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1133 on 2016-07-25

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

@2ROS0: "(I don't want to do that for some smaller tasks)" Exactly the same with me.

I am looking for an API programming language equivalent of `$ rosrun tf tf_echo [frame1] [frame2]`

I'm also trying to see how this command works:

```
void transformPoint (const std::string &target_frame, const Stamped< tf::Point > &stamped_in, Stamped< tf::Point > &stamped_out) const
```

but I don't see an indication for the current/reference frame which is not too good.

---

Originally posted by [BluPlana](https://answers.ros.org/users/29054/bluplana/) with karma: 26 on 2017-02-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-02-24**:\

> I don't see an indication for the current/reference frame

The input to `transformPoint(..)` is a `Stamped<tf::Point>`. *Stamped* in ROS parlance means: "with a header", which implies that the `frame_id` of the hdr is valid. That is the source frame. `target_frame` is the .. target.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-02-24**:
Note: the `Stamped` suffix is used on msgs to indicate that it has a `Header`. In this case the terminology / naming convention was carried over, but `Stamped` is not a msg def. Member names are identical though: [api/Stamped](http://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/tf/html/c++/classtf_1_1Stamped.html).

**Comment by [BluPlana](https://answers.ros.org/users/29054/bluplana/) on 2017-02-24**:
@gvdhoorn: Thanks. Your response is really helpful!

for points that are not stamped, what happens?

**Comment by [BluPlana](https://answers.ros.org/users/29054/bluplana/) on 2017-02-24**:
However, for points without stamps, how does one know the operating frame? My point doesn't have any stamp, but I'm sure it is defined in the /world. However, when I perform Inverse kinematics on my KDL chain to that point, my IK_solver seems to take the endeff to the point in the chain_root_frame

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-02-24**:\

> for points that are not stamped, what happens?

well, for this particular overload you'll get a compiler error.

But in general you'll have to either convert your `Point` to a `Stamped` version (ie: by providing the required info), or use one of the more suited overloads.